# Subversion client hangs occasionally

Tags: svn, centos, export, svn-checkout

I have a server with CentOS release 6.4 (Final) OS installation, and subversion package with version:1.6.11, release:9.el6_4. I use Apache + WebDav module to connect to my repositories through http protocol.

Recently I migrated my svn repositories from my old server which had almost identical configuration as the current one.

When I do a checkout or export from the new server, In about 50% of the cases when I run the checkout/export command, the process hangs and I am unable to exit it because everyting I type does not affect the console. The last output message when I run in debug mode is:

```
Request sent; retry is 0.
```

Here is the whole log of my export command with neon-debug-mask=511 set.

[Click Here to View the Log](http://pastebin.com/dQm1xN0w)

Could this be related to SVN itself or I have some networking problem? Any ideas on further debugging?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that I had networking problems. My server was connected to a switch and then to router.
I connected the server to the router directly and now all is fine.